# Moving Infected Files to Trash versus Quarantining them

Tags: antivirus, quarantine

When you run an AntiVirus, typically they give you the option of quarantining the infected files. I remember when I was a kid I would move them to the trash bin instead. My question is, which method - quarantining infected files or moving to trash - is most secure? If so, why?

It's my understanding that when we 'quarantine' files the AntiVirus just moves them to another location. What makes this location secure? Can an infected file be dangerous even after being moved to the trash can?

Comment: This might be worth a read: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64443/can-malware-be-dangerous-even-when-quarantined

Answer (score 1):

A quarantine is a place for you to review files that caused alerts. It's not about security, but convenience.